# Calendar details of Public folder in M365

Tags: powershell, calendar, public-folders, exchange-online

I would like to get the schedule from the calendar in the public folder on M365.  But I can't find any PowerShell can retrieve it.  Is that have another method?

```
Get-PublicFolderItemStatistics -Identity "\Schedule" |
    Select Subject,LastModificationTime,HasAttachments,ItemType,MessageSize
```

But only have the created time on the result.

```
Subject              : Internal Meeting
LastModificationTime : 06/12/2023 8:54:37
HasAttachments       : False
ItemType             : IPM.Appointment
MessageSize          : 5.651 KB (5,787 bytes)
```